# How to change ionic background color for an single page to two different colors

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I´m trying to set the background color of a page in ionic project to two different colors, but this page have an  element on it, so i´m having problems with it. The html code of the page is this:

```
<ion-content>
<div style="height: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; text-align: center;">

  <ion-card>
  <ion-card-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      <ion-item-divider>
      <ion-label>
        <img width="150" src = "./assets/images/logo.png">
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item-divider>
      <ion-label>
        <br/>Acceder
      </ion-label>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-card-header>
<ion-card-content padding = "true">
  <form #form="ngForm"  method="post">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input [(ngModel)] = "postData.username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Usuario"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-input [(ngModel)] = "postData.password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item lines ='none'>
      <a routerLink='/signup'>Create account</a>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-button expand="block" share = "round" color="primary" (click) ="loginAction()">Login</ion-button>
  </form>
</ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

Sorry for my english, is not my mother tongue

Comment: can you try "background-color='red'" in parent div ?

Comment: Doesn´t work, but also, that only change the background to one color, i wanted to put two different colors on it, 50/50. Thanks for answer